# How to set timeout wcf on xmarin droid

Tags: xamarin.android, monodevelop

My application connects with a WCF service (.NET 4.5). I build proxy using slsvcutil (silverligth 5) and Works fine. 
but I´ve having problems with timeout. I get an error over 1 minute.
this it´s my code:

```
                    BasicHttpBinding bindin = new BasicHttpBinding();
                    bindin.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 267386880;

                    var timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
                    bindin.SendTimeout = timeout;
                    bindin.OpenTimeout = timeout;
                    bindin.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;

                    wcf = new ServicioInasaClient(bindin, new EndpointAddress(editHost.Text));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with:

```
 wcf.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = timeout;
```